# Kill an activity when orientation changes

Tags: android

I would like to know if it is possible to ask Android not to reload one Activity when orientation changes (I want to reload others but to kill this one !!).

I have checked the activity properties that I can set in the manifest but no one seems to allow that.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public boolean onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
    return true;
}

public onCreate() {
    if(getLastNonConfigurationInstance() != null) {
        finish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is simple, in your activity override [onConfigurationChanged(Configuration config)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged%28android.content.res.Configuration%29) and kill the activity inside of that.

Ex:

```
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged (Configuration newConfig)
    {
          super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
          finish();
    }
```

This will cause the activity to be killed when a configuration change takes place. In the manifest under [config changes](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#configChanges) select orientation for your activity. You can check which type of orientation it is changing to by looking at newConfig.orientation and compare it to the constants for portrait and landscape in the Configuration class.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to know if it is possible to ask Android not to reload one Activity when orientation changes (I want to reload others but to kill this one !!).

Possible? Sure. A good idea? No. Users will get very confused if a simple twist of their wrist causes the current activity to go away. They might think that your app is broken.

Ideally, you allow users to use your activities in any orientation they desire. It is their device, not yours.

If, for some reason, some activity only makes sense in one orientation (e.g., landscape), use the `android:orientation` attribute in the `<activity>` element in the manifest to keep it in that orientation.

Comment: No, you don't understand, user can use my application as he wants. I just want to kill this activity (which is a dialog box) but I start it again when my app is reloaded (so the user don't see that it has been killed).

Comment: @TheAngel: Android automatically destroys and recreates activities on a configuration change, by default.

Comment: Yes I know. I explain : I am making a game, I have 2 threads, one is the default one (I use it only for UI) and the other is used to update the game. I don't know if it is the best way to do that, but when a configuration changed happens, I only save the content of the game thread (I save the same datas when user asks to save manually). So when, configuration changed happens, the UI thread is not restored in a state which understand that there is a dialog box. So I prefer close the dialog box and wait that the game thread ask again to show it !